# Insert full qualification in code notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, dataset, resharper

I am using resharper tool for reviewing my code but when I comes to the line

```
DataSet dsContactFormInfo=null;
```

then resharper shows a notification that use full qualification after this it will become like this

```
 System.Data.DataSet dsContactFormInfo=null;
```

So actually what is the difference If I use System.Data.DataSet in place of Dataset?

does it make any effect in performance of code in point of optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper is is just giving you an option for formatting your code.

There is no difference at run time since the compiler will look at your `using` statements at the top of the file, find the unique accessible type `DataSet` within them and use that. If there are multiple options you'll get a compile error, otherwise the successfully compiled referenced dll will use `System.Data.DataSet` in your example, regardless of which you wrote in the source code.